# Multiples of a number oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

How do you check if the content of a field is a multiple of 2 in oracle sql

```
n_id     |     n_content
-------------------------
1        |     Balloon
2        |     Drill
3        |     Cup
4        |     Bottle            
5        |     Pencil
6        |     Ball
```

I have tried:

```
select*from num_w where (n_id%2>0);
```

and also

```
select*from num_w where n_id%2=0;
```

Neither of these worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasn't this multiple of 5 a few seconds ago? :)

Anyway, in Oracle I believe the query would be:

```
select * from num_w where MOD(n_id,2) = 0;
```